# How to keep content together in XSL FO tables

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have XSL-FO with region-before, region-after, and region-body which has a table having 6 columns. The second column has 3 lines of data (name, address, city/state/zip). We render this into PDF.

If I simply apply my data, I will get a row at the end of the page, where the 2nd column has 1 line of text on the current page, and 2 lines end up on the next page.

If I apply keep-together="always" (or keep-together.within-column="always") my table starts on the 2nd page.

How can I get my data to page-break correctly? If I have not provided enough information, please comment and I will try to provide it.

Edit: XSL-FO attached; Added Stylesheet and XML; Added the rest of the XSLT

XML Data:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AS400_ELVPLOC00Collection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <COL_FILL_MODE>0</COL_FILL_MODE>
  <IS_CHANGED>false</IS_CHANGED>
  <IS_CHILDREN>true</IS_CHILDREN>
  <SLMR_ERROR_LIST />
  <ObjList>
    <AS400_ELVPLOC00>
      <ID>0</ID>
  <DOC_LINK_ID>0</DOC_LINK_ID>
  <EMAIL_LINK_ID>0</EMAIL_LINK_ID>
  <IS_CHANGED>false</IS_CHANGED>
  <IS_CHILDREN>true</IS_CHILDREN>
  <OBJ_TYPE>AS400_ELVPLOC00</OBJ_TYPE>
  <CRTD_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CRTD_DT>
  <MODFD_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</MODFD_DT>
  <SLMR_ERROR_LIST />
  <ELBLDGCD>11966</ELBLDGCD>
  <ELBLDGCD_DISPLAY>11966</ELBLDGCD_DISPLAY>
  <ELBLDGNM>TEST COMPANY</ELBLDGNM>
  <ELLSTNUM>123</ELLSTNUM>
  <ELLDIR></ELLDIR>
  <ELLRDNUM>0</ELLRDNUM>
  <ELLSTNM1>Nowhere</ELLSTNM1>
  <ELLTYP1>St</ELLTYP1>
  <ELLCITY>HARRISBURG</ELLCITY>
  <ELLSTATE>PA</ELLSTATE>
  <ELLZIPCD>17111</ELLZIPCD>
  <ELLZIPCD_DISPLAY>18970</ELLZIPCD_DISPLAY>
  <ELLZIPSX>0</ELLZIPSX>
  <ELLZIPSX_DISPLAY />
  <LOC_STREET_DISPLAY>123 Nowhere St</LOC_STREET_DISPLAY>
  <LOC_STREET_DISPLAY2> </LOC_STREET_DISPLAY2>
  <LOC_DISPLAY_NONUM>123 Nowhere St&lt;br /&gt;HARRISBURG PA 17111</LOC_DISPLAY_NONUM>
  <ELLCNTY>42017</ELLCNTY>
  <ELLCNTY_NAME>Bucks</ELLCNTY_NAME>
  <ELLCURRYY>0</ELLCURRYY>
  <ELLCURRMM>0</ELLCURRMM>
  <ELLCURRDD>0</ELLCURRDD>
  <ELLCurrStatus_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELLCurrStatus_DT>
  <FEE_CO_ID>0</FEE_CO_ID>
  <INSPTR_ID>0</INSPTR_ID>
  <ELLUPDTYY>0</ELLUPDTYY>
  <ELLUPDTMM>0</ELLUPDTMM>
  <ELLUPDTDD>0</ELLUPDTDD>
  <ELLLastUpdate_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELLLastUpdate_DT>
  <ELLPASTYY>0</ELLPASTYY>
  <ELLPASTMM>0</ELLPASTMM>
  <ELLPASTDD>0</ELLPASTDD>
  <ELEPastStat_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELEPastStat_DT>
  <AS400_ELVPEQP_COL>
    <COL_FILL_MODE>0</COL_FILL_MODE>
    <IS_CHANGED>false</IS_CHANGED>
    <IS_CHILDREN>true</IS_CHILDREN>
    <SLMR_ERROR_LIST />
    <ObjList>
      <AS400_ELVPEQP00>
        <ID>114224</ID>
        <DOC_LINK_ID>0</DOC_LINK_ID>
        <EMAIL_LINK_ID>0</EMAIL_LINK_ID>
        <IS_CHANGED>false</IS_CHANGED>
        <IS_CHILDREN>true</IS_CHILDREN>
        <OBJ_TYPE>AS400_ELVPEQP00</OBJ_TYPE>
        <CRTD_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CRTD_DT>
        <MODFD_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</MODFD_DT>
        <SLMR_ERROR_LIST />
        <ELBLDGCD>11966</ELBLDGCD>
        <ELEEQNO>1</ELEEQNO>
        <ELEEQNO_DISPLAY>001</ELEEQNO_DISPLAY>
        <ELEDTINY>1947</ELEDTINY>
        <ELEDTINM>10</ELEDTINM>
        <ELEDTIND>2</ELEDTIND>
        <ELEInitInsp_DT>1947-10-02T00:00:00</ELEInitInsp_DT>
        <ELEIRSLT>P</ELEIRSLT>
        <ELEICDTY>0</ELEICDTY>
        <ELEICDTM>0</ELEICDTM>
        <ELEICDTD>0</ELEICDTD>
        <ELEClear_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEClear_DT>
        <ELPERMTNO>194703851</ELPERMTNO>
        <ELEPERMID>N</ELEPERMID>
        <ELEDTISY>0</ELEDTISY>
        <ELEDTISM>0</ELEDTISM>
        <ELEDTISD>0</ELEDTISD>
        <ELEPermitIssued_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEPermitIssued_DT>
        <ELELSEAL />
        <ELEYCEXP>0</ELEYCEXP>
        <ELEMCEXP>0</ELEMCEXP>
        <ELECEXP_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELECEXP_DT>
        <ELEYCISS>0</ELEYCISS>
        <ELEMCISS>0</ELEMCISS>
        <ELOFLNUM>11966</ELOFLNUM>
        <ELERPNUM>11966</ELERPNUM>
        <ELETYPELV>F</ELETYPELV>
        <ELEINSPD>2</ELEINSPD>
        <ELEDTWINY>0</ELEDTWINY>
        <ELEDTWINM>0</ELEDTWINM>
        <ELEDTWIND>0</ELEDTWIND>
        <ELEMajRepair_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEMajRepair_DT>
        <ELEWCDTY>0</ELEWCDTY>
        <ELEWCDTM>0</ELEWCDTM>
        <ELEWCDTD>0</ELEWCDTD>
        <ELEMajRepairClear_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEMajRepairClear_DT>
        <ELEDTLINY>2008</ELEDTLINY>
        <ELEDTLINM>2</ELEDTLINM>
        <ELEDTLIND>21</ELEDTLIND>
        <ELELastInsp_DT>2008-02-21T00:00:00</ELELastInsp_DT>
        <ELELAST_INSP_ID>1369887</ELELAST_INSP_ID>
        <ELEUPDTYY>0</ELEUPDTYY>
        <ELEUPDTMM>0</ELEUPDTMM>
        <ELEUPDTDD>0</ELEUPDTDD>
        <ELELastUpdate_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELELastUpdate_DT>
        <ELELocId>0</ELELocId>
        <ELEBldgOpwnId>0</ELEBldgOpwnId>
        <ELERespOwnId>0</ELERespOwnId>
        <ELEPassID>0</ELEPassID>
        <ELESkiID>0</ELESkiID>
        <ELEWclID>0</ELEWclID>
        <ELEECOCD_ID>0</ELEECOCD_ID>
        <ELEEORIG_ID>0</ELEEORIG_ID>
        <FIRST_INSP_ID>0</FIRST_INSP_ID>
        <LAST_MAJ_REP_INSP_ID>0</LAST_MAJ_REP_INSP_ID>
      </AS400_ELVPEQP00>
      <AS400_ELVPEQP00>
        <ID>114225</ID>
        <DOC_LINK_ID>0</DOC_LINK_ID>
        <EMAIL_LINK_ID>0</EMAIL_LINK_ID>
        <IS_CHANGED>false</IS_CHANGED>
        <IS_CHILDREN>true</IS_CHILDREN>
        <OBJ_TYPE>AS400_ELVPEQP00</OBJ_TYPE>
        <CRTD_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CRTD_DT>
        <MODFD_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</MODFD_DT>
        <SLMR_ERROR_LIST />
        <ELBLDGCD>11966</ELBLDGCD>
        <ELEEQNO>2</ELEEQNO>
        <ELEEQNO_DISPLAY>002</ELEEQNO_DISPLAY>
        <ELEDTINY>1947</ELEDTINY>
        <ELEDTINM>10</ELEDTINM>
        <ELEDTIND>2</ELEDTIND>
        <ELEInitInsp_DT>1947-10-02T00:00:00</ELEInitInsp_DT>
        <ELEIRSLT>P</ELEIRSLT>
        <ELEICDTY>0</ELEICDTY>
        <ELEICDTM>0</ELEICDTM>
        <ELEICDTD>0</ELEICDTD>
        <ELEClear_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEClear_DT>
        <ELPERMTNO>194703851</ELPERMTNO>
        <ELEPERMID>N</ELEPERMID>
        <ELEDTISY>0</ELEDTISY>
        <ELEDTISM>0</ELEDTISM>
        <ELEDTISD>0</ELEDTISD>
        <ELEPermitIssued_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEPermitIssued_DT>
        <ELELSEAL />
        <ELEYCEXP>0</ELEYCEXP>
        <ELEMCEXP>0</ELEMCEXP>
        <ELECEXP_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELECEXP_DT>
        <ELEYCISS>0</ELEYCISS>
        <ELEMCISS>0</ELEMCISS>
        <ELOFLNUM>11966</ELOFLNUM>
        <ELERPNUM>11966</ELERPNUM>
        <ELETYPELV>F</ELETYPELV>
        <ELEINSPD>2</ELEINSPD>
        <ELEDTWINY>0</ELEDTWINY>
        <ELEDTWINM>0</ELEDTWINM>
        <ELEDTWIND>0</ELEDTWIND>
        <ELEMajRepair_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEMajRepair_DT>
        <ELEWCDTY>0</ELEWCDTY>
        <ELEWCDTM>0</ELEWCDTM>
        <ELEWCDTD>0</ELEWCDTD>
        <ELEMajRepairClear_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEMajRepairClear_DT>
        <ELEDTLINY>2008</ELEDTLINY>
        <ELEDTLINM>2</ELEDTLINM>
        <ELEDTLIND>21</ELEDTLIND>
        <ELELastInsp_DT>2008-02-21T00:00:00</ELELastInsp_DT>
        <ELELAST_INSP_ID>1369887</ELELAST_INSP_ID>
        <ELEUPDTYY>0</ELEUPDTYY>
        <ELEUPDTMM>0</ELEUPDTMM>
        <ELEUPDTDD>0</ELEUPDTDD>
        <ELELastUpdate_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELELastUpdate_DT>
        <ELELocId>0</ELELocId>
        <ELEBldgOpwnId>0</ELEBldgOpwnId>
        <ELERespOwnId>0</ELERespOwnId>
        <ELEPassID>0</ELEPassID>
        <ELESkiID>0</ELESkiID>
        <ELEWclID>0</ELEWclID>
        <ELEECOCD_ID>0</ELEECOCD_ID>
        <ELEEORIG_ID>0</ELEEORIG_ID>
        <FIRST_INSP_ID>0</FIRST_INSP_ID>
        <LAST_MAJ_REP_INSP_ID>0</LAST_MAJ_REP_INSP_ID>
      </AS400_ELVPEQP00>
    </ObjList>
    <Sort_Expression />
    <Sort_Expression_List />
    <Sort_Direction>Asc</Sort_Direction>
    <SEARCH_ELBLDGCD>0</SEARCH_ELBLDGCD>
    <SEARCH_ELEEQNO>0</SEARCH_ELEEQNO>
    <SEARCH_ELEFLNUM>0</SEARCH_ELEFLNUM>
    <SEARCH_ELERPNUM>0</SEARCH_ELERPNUM>
    <SEARCH_ELPERMTNO>0</SEARCH_ELPERMTNO>
    <SEARCH_ELPERMTNO_LIST />
    <SEARCH_INSPTRID>0</SEARCH_INSPTRID>
    <SEARCH_INSPNDT_START>12:00:00 AM</SEARCH_INSPNDT_START>
    <SEARCH_INSPNDT_END>12:00:00 AM</SEARCH_INSPNDT_END>
  </AS400_ELVPEQP_COL>
  <LastEqpNum>0</LastEqpNum>
  <NumOfEqp>0</NumOfEqp>
  <PRVNC>0</PRVNC>
  <CTRY>0</CTRY>
  <DIVN>ELV</DIVN>
  <FILE_NUMBER>0</FILE_NUMBER>
  <OWNER_ID>0</OWNER_ID>
  <Original_ObjType>AS400_ELVPLOC00</Original_ObjType>
  <ASGD_WRKLD_INSPTR_ID>0</ASGD_WRKLD_INSPTR_ID>
</AS400_ELVPLOC00>
<AS400_ELVPLOC00>
  <ID>0</ID>
  <DOC_LINK_ID>0</DOC_LINK_ID>
  <EMAIL_LINK_ID>0</EMAIL_LINK_ID>
  <IS_CHANGED>false</IS_CHANGED>
  <IS_CHILDREN>true</IS_CHILDREN>
  <OBJ_TYPE>AS400_ELVPLOC00</OBJ_TYPE>
  <CRTD_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CRTD_DT>
  <MODFD_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</MODFD_DT>
  <SLMR_ERROR_LIST />
  <ELBLDGCD>26778</ELBLDGCD>
  <ELBLDGCD_DISPLAY>26778</ELBLDGCD_DISPLAY>
  <ELBLDGNM>ANOTHER COMPANY</ELBLDGNM>
  <ELLSTNUM />
  <ELLDIR>E</ELLDIR>
  <ELLRDNUM>0</ELLRDNUM>
  <ELLSTNM1>POST</ELLSTNM1>
  <ELLTYP1>RD</ELLTYP1>
  <ELLCITY>HARRISBURG</ELLCITY>
  <ELLSTATE>PA</ELLSTATE>
  <ELLZIPCD>17111</ELLZIPCD>
  <ELLZIPCD_DISPLAY>19067</ELLZIPCD_DISPLAY>
  <ELLZIPSX>0</ELLZIPSX>
  <ELLZIPSX_DISPLAY />
  <LOC_STREET_DISPLAY>E POST RD</LOC_STREET_DISPLAY>
  <LOC_STREET_DISPLAY2> </LOC_STREET_DISPLAY2>
  <LOC_DISPLAY_NONUM>ANOTHER COMPANY&lt;br /&gt;E POST RD&lt;br /&gt;HARRISBURG PA 17111</LOC_DISPLAY_NONUM>
  <ELLCNTY>42017</ELLCNTY>
  <ELLCNTY_NAME>Bucks</ELLCNTY_NAME>
  <ELLCURRYY>0</ELLCURRYY>
  <ELLCURRMM>0</ELLCURRMM>
  <ELLCURRDD>0</ELLCURRDD>
  <ELLCurrStatus_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELLCurrStatus_DT>
  <FEE_CO_ID>0</FEE_CO_ID>
  <INSPTR_ID>0</INSPTR_ID>
  <ELLUPDTYY>0</ELLUPDTYY>
  <ELLUPDTMM>0</ELLUPDTMM>
  <ELLUPDTDD>0</ELLUPDTDD>
  <ELLLastUpdate_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELLLastUpdate_DT>
  <ELLPASTYY>0</ELLPASTYY>
  <ELLPASTMM>0</ELLPASTMM>
  <ELLPASTDD>0</ELLPASTDD>
  <ELEPastStat_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELEPastStat_DT>
  <AS400_ELVPEQP_COL>
    <COL_FILL_MODE>0</COL_FILL_MODE>
    <IS_CHANGED>false</IS_CHANGED>
    <IS_CHILDREN>true</IS_CHILDREN>
    <SLMR_ERROR_LIST />
    <ObjList>
      <AS400_ELVPEQP00>
        <ID>77581</ID>
        <DOC_LINK_ID>0</DOC_LINK_ID>
        <EMAIL_LINK_ID>0</EMAIL_LINK_ID>
        <IS_CHANGED>false</IS_CHANGED>
        <IS_CHILDREN>true</IS_CHILDREN>
        <OBJ_TYPE>AS400_ELVPEQP00</OBJ_TYPE>
        <CRTD_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CRTD_DT>
        <MODFD_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</MODFD_DT>
        <SLMR_ERROR_LIST />
        <ELBLDGCD>26778</ELBLDGCD>
        <ELEEQNO>7</ELEEQNO>
        <ELEEQNO_DISPLAY>007</ELEEQNO_DISPLAY>
        <ELEDTINY>0</ELEDTINY>
        <ELEDTINM>0</ELEDTINM>
        <ELEDTIND>0</ELEDTIND>
        <ELEInitInsp_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEInitInsp_DT>
        <ELEIRSLT />
        <ELEICDTY>0</ELEICDTY>
        <ELEICDTM>0</ELEICDTM>
        <ELEICDTD>0</ELEICDTD>
        <ELEClear_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEClear_DT>
        <ELPERMTNO>0</ELPERMTNO>
        <ELEPERMID>M0</ELEPERMID>
        <ELEDTISY>0</ELEDTISY>
        <ELEDTISM>0</ELEDTISM>
        <ELEDTISD>0</ELEDTISD>
        <ELEPermitIssued_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEPermitIssued_DT>
        <ELELSEAL />
        <ELEYCEXP>0</ELEYCEXP>
        <ELEMCEXP>0</ELEMCEXP>
        <ELECEXP_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELECEXP_DT>
            <ELEYCISS>0</ELEYCISS>
            <ELEMCISS>0</ELEMCISS>
            <ELOFLNUM>26778</ELOFLNUM>
            <ELERPNUM>26778</ELERPNUM>
            <ELETYPELV>F</ELETYPELV>
            <ELEINSPD>2</ELEINSPD>
            <ELEDTWINY>0</ELEDTWINY>
            <ELEDTWINM>0</ELEDTWINM>
            <ELEDTWIND>0</ELEDTWIND>
            <ELEMajRepair_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEMajRepair_DT>
            <ELEWCDTY>0</ELEWCDTY>
            <ELEWCDTM>0</ELEWCDTM>
            <ELEWCDTD>0</ELEWCDTD>
            <ELEMajRepairClear_DT>1900-01-01T00:00:00</ELEMajRepairClear_DT>
            <ELEDTLINY>2010</ELEDTLINY>
            <ELEDTLINM>6</ELEDTLINM>
            <ELEDTLIND>3</ELEDTLIND>
            <ELELastInsp_DT>2010-06-03T00:00:00</ELELastInsp_DT>
            <ELELAST_INSP_ID>1547374</ELELAST_INSP_ID>
            <ELEUPDTYY>0</ELEUPDTYY>
            <ELEUPDTMM>0</ELEUPDTMM>
            <ELEUPDTDD>0</ELEUPDTDD>
            <ELELastUpdate_DT>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ELELastUpdate_DT>
            <ELELocId>0</ELELocId>
            <ELEBldgOpwnId>0</ELEBldgOpwnId>
            <ELERespOwnId>0</ELERespOwnId>
            <ELEPassID>0</ELEPassID>
            <ELESkiID>0</ELESkiID>
            <ELEWclID>0</ELEWclID>
            <ELEECOCD_ID>0</ELEECOCD_ID>
            <ELEEORIG_ID>0</ELEEORIG_ID>
            <FIRST_INSP_ID>0</FIRST_INSP_ID>
            <LAST_MAJ_REP_INSP_ID>0</LAST_MAJ_REP_INSP_ID>
          </AS400_ELVPEQP00>
        </ObjList>
        <Sort_Expression />
        <Sort_Expression_List />
        <Sort_Direction>Asc</Sort_Direction>
        <SEARCH_ELBLDGCD>0</SEARCH_ELBLDGCD>
        <SEARCH_ELEEQNO>0</SEARCH_ELEEQNO>
        <SEARCH_ELEFLNUM>0</SEARCH_ELEFLNUM>
        <SEARCH_ELERPNUM>0</SEARCH_ELERPNUM>
        <SEARCH_ELPERMTNO>0</SEARCH_ELPERMTNO>
        <SEARCH_ELPERMTNO_LIST />
        <SEARCH_INSPTRID>0</SEARCH_INSPTRID>
        <SEARCH_INSPNDT_START>12:00:00 AM</SEARCH_INSPNDT_START>
        <SEARCH_INSPNDT_END>12:00:00 AM</SEARCH_INSPNDT_END>
      </AS400_ELVPEQP_COL>
      <LastEqpNum>0</LastEqpNum>
      <NumOfEqp>0</NumOfEqp>
      <PRVNC>0</PRVNC>
      <CTRY>0</CTRY>
      <DIVN>ELV</DIVN>
      <FILE_NUMBER>0</FILE_NUMBER>
      <OWNER_ID>0</OWNER_ID>
      <Original_ObjType>AS400_ELVPLOC00</Original_ObjType>
      <ASGD_WRKLD_INSPTR_ID>0</ASGD_WRKLD_INSPTR_ID>
    </AS400_ELVPLOC00>
  </ObjList>
  <Sort_Expression />
  <Sort_Expression_List />
  <Sort_Direction>Asc</Sort_Direction>
  <SEARCH_ELBLDGCD>0</SEARCH_ELBLDGCD>
  <SEARCH_ELBLDGNM />
  <SEARCH_ELLCITY />
  <SEARCH_ELOFLNUM>0</SEARCH_ELOFLNUM>
  <SEARCH_ELLSTNAME />
  <SEARCH_Counties>42017,42075</SEARCH_Counties>
  <SEARCH_FromDate>2011-01-01T00:00:00</SEARCH_FromDate>
  <SEARCH_ToDate>2014-06-30T00:00:00</SEARCH_ToDate>
</AS400_ELVPLOC00Collection>
```

Print_Stylesheet.txt (attribute-sets)

```
  <xsl:attribute-set name="table">
   <xsl:attribute name="font-family">Arial</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">10pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="table-layout">fixed</xsl:attribute> 
    <xsl:attribute name="space-before">10pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="space-after">10pt</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="table.data.th" >
    <xsl:attribute name="border-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-color">black</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-width">1pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-start">0.3em</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-end">0.2em</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-before">2pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-after">2pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">9pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="table.data.td_title" >
    <xsl:attribute name="border-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-color">black</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-width">1pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-start">0.3em</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-end">0.2em</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-before">2pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-after">2pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="table.data.td_data" >
    <xsl:attribute name="border-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-color">black</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-width">1pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">9pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-start">0.5em</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-end">0.3em</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-before">2pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-after">2pt</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="table_PLAN_APRVL">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-family">Arial</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">9pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="line-height">14pt</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="table.data.td_titleCell">
    <xsl:attribute name="line-height">10pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">9pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-start">0.3em</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-end">0.2em</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-before">1pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-after">1pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-left-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-left-width">thin</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-right-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-right-width">thin</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-top-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-top-width">thin</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="table.data.td_innerTitleCell">
    <xsl:attribute name="vertical-align">sub</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">right</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">9pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-end">0.1em</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-before">1pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-after">1pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="table.data.td_innerCell">
    <xsl:attribute name="vertical-align">sub</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">9pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-before">1pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-after">1pt</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

   <xsl:attribute-set name="OCR.Data">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-family">OCR A Extended</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">13pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">normal</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-color">black</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>
```

Section from XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <!--Style Sheet-->
  <!--Helper Tools-->
  <xsl:variable name="ind" select="0" />
  <xsl:attribute-set name="table.cell">
    <xsl:attribute name="border-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-color">black</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-width">normal</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">7pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-family">Times New Roman</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-before">2pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-after">2pt</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:key name="county" match="ObjList/AS400_ELVPLOC00" use="ELLCNTY_NAME" />

  <xsl:template match="AS400_ELVPLOC00Collection">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
                  page-height="11in"
                  page-width="8.5in"
                  margin-top="0.125in"
                  margin-bottom="0.125in"
                  margin-left="0.325in"
                  margin-right="0.325in">

          <fo:region-body margin-top="1.125in"
                      margin-bottom="0.75in"
                      margin-left="0in"
                      margin-right="1in"
            />
          <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="1in" />
          <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="0.0in" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
        <!-- Page Header-->
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        </fo:static-content>

        <!--Footer-->
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after" >
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:for-each select="ObjList/AS400_ELVPLOC00[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('county',ELLCNTY_NAME)[1])]">

        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <xsl:for-each select="ObjList/AS400_ELVPLOC00[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('county',ELLCNTY_NAME)[1])]">

        <fo:table xsl:use-attribute-sets="table" space-after="0pt" break-after="page">
          <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="0.75in" />
          <!-- LOC NO -->
          <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="2.85in" />
          <!-- LOCATION -->
          <fo:table-column column-number="3" column-width="1.5in" />
          <!-- EQP/TYPE -->
          <fo:table-column column-number="4" column-width="1.25in" />
          <!-- INSP DATE -->
          <fo:table-column column-number="5" column-width="0.125in" />
          <!-- ? -->
          <fo:table-column column-number="6" column-width="2.0in" />
          <!-- HISTORY -->
          <fo:table-header>
            <!-- Grid Header -->
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                <fo:block>
                  <xsl:text>FOR </xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ELLCNTY_NAME" />
                  <xsl:text> COUNTY</xsl:text>
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="4">

              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block padding-after="10pt">
                  LOC NO
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                <fo:block>
                  LOCATION
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                <fo:block>
                  EQP/TYPE
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                <fo:block>
                  INSP DATE
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                <fo:block>

                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                <fo:block>
                  HISTORY
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-header>

          <!-- Table Grid -->
          <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('county',ELLCNTY_NAME)">
              <xsl:sort select="ELBLDGCD_DISPLAY" />
              <fo:table-row padding-after="4pt">
                <fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ELBLDGCD_DISPLAY" />
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding-after="5pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    <fo:block>
                      <xsl:value-of select="ELBLDGNM"/>
                    </fo:block>
                    <fo:block>
                      <xsl:value-of select="LOC_STREET_DISPLAY"/>
                    </fo:block>
                    <fo:block>
                      <xsl:value-of select="ELLCITY"/>
                      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="ELLSTATE"/>
                      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="ELLZIPCD"/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding-after="5pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding-after="5pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding-after="5pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding-after="5pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>

          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Post the sample XSL FO you are working with

Comment: Is this question specific to msxsl?

Comment: Well (1) you posted the XSL not the XSL FO, without the XSL FO or the XML it's impossible to tell how many rows you have in your table or even test it. (2) It's also not possible to see what formatting you have going on in things like xsl:use-attribute-sets="table" which you have not included.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know if my question would be enough or not. What do you mean XSL and XSL FO? The sample code (now in the third section of code) is from the XSLT file we are using to do the transform.

Comment: Well, the XSL is not well formed. Did you miss some tags like ending a for-each and ending a flow at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing a few issues in your posted XSL and examining the results, I believe what you want is the whole row in the repeating table is always kept together on a page. If yes, then you would do this in your XSL:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="key('county',ELLCNTY_NAME)">
            <xsl:sort select="ELBLDGCD_DISPLAY" />
            <fo:table-row padding-after="4pt" keep-together.within-page="always">
```

You can get the same effect by setting that value on the exact table-cell:

```
          <fo:table-cell padding-after="5pt" keep-together.within-page="always">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ELBLDGNM"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="LOC_STREET_DISPLAY"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ELLCITY"/>
                            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ELLSTATE"/>
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ELLZIPCD"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
```

Or even the containing block that contains all the lines inside the table cell. The difference would be whether this is the *only* thing you want kept together or if you want the whole row kept together.

Also note, this has nothing to do with MSXML, that tag should be removed. It is a pure XSL FO keep question and does not matter what XSLT engine you use.

The resulting PDF shows that those cells are not broken from page to page:

[image]